# How can I stop a docker container at a certain time? (24h reset)

Tags: docker

I want to stop a docker container at 5am server time, but can't find any solution in the docker documentation. Do I need a manager for this kind of action?

I'm pretty new to docker and maybe I am missing it.

Comment: you can do that inside dockerfile too inside cron docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to setup a cronjob:

```
0 5 * * * docker stop <ID-OR-NAME>
```

Comment: Or a [systemd timer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) if that's your system's native init system.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to have the docker 24h and then stop you can use:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu timeout 86400
```

Where 86400 is 24h in seconds. But the idea of cronjob is better if you want to stop it at same time every day to restart.